# Can I develop Unity while running Maverick (10.10)? Or do I have to run Natty?

Tags: 10.10, unity, 11.04, development, bazaar

I've just joined the Ubuntu Unity developers Bazaar repository and am eager to get started on hacking the code! Do I need to run Natty to be able to do this? Or can I simply use Maverick? I'd prefer to be able to work on Maverick because it is stable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're developing a [Unity Place](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Places) then you can do that one either 10.10 or 11.04.

However for most Unity development you need to be on 11.04 as it's changed significantly from 10.10. You can either do that with virtualization or [creating a separate USB stick](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key).

We have set aside a bunch of "bitesize" bugs for people to get started hacking on Unity, and we'll probably have some IRC tutorial sessions too:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Bitesize
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDeveloperWeek

Comment: Thank you. I've got a problem installing 11.04a1 as its own partition on my computer, though. It always starts the installation, then freezes and doesn't do anything. I press Ctrl-Alt-F1, type `ls` and get the message `Too many files open on system`. Can you help me?

Comment: @Nathan Probably best to wait until it's more baked, closer to beta.

Comment: Is 11.04a2 easier to install? Does the installer actually work?

Comment: Depends on your hardware really - best thing to do is give the LiveCD a shot or use virtualization.

Comment: It seems as though I can develop Unity 2D on Maverick, though.